# Can a normal ethereum address receive an USDC token?

Tags: ethereum

I want to receive some USD coin, for this special wallet is required or can any ethereum address receive it?

Comment: Hi my friend, have you ever got this to work? I have USDC on an address but I cannot send them using the "transfer" function. Do you know how to send these USDC somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible as USDC follows the ERC20 standard, so you don't need a special wallet for it.

Comment: The ABI of this USDC contract has no basic ERC20 functions, so how can i make an instance of this contract to transfer tokens

https://etherscan.io/token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#code

There is not transfer function in ABI code.